# The maximum possible value of $ (xv - yu)^2 $ over the surface ...

Tags: trigonometry

The maximum possible value of $ (xv - yu)^2 $ over the surface given by the equations

$ x^2 + y^2 = 4 $ and $ u^2 + v^2 = 9 $ is :

I solved it and my answer comes out to be $9$ but the correct answer is $36$.

Here is what I did :

Put $ x = r_1\cos\theta$ and   $y = r_1\sin\theta $

$ u = r_2\sin\theta $ and $ v = r_2\cos\theta$

Using $ x^2 + y^2 = 4 $ and $ u^2 + v^2 = 9 $

we get $ r_1 = \sqrt 2 $ and $ r_2 = \frac 3{\sqrt 2} $

Now $ (xv - yu)^2 = (r_1r_2)^2(\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta)^2 $

$= 9(1-2\sin^2\theta)^2$

Now this will be maximum when $ (1- 2\sin^2\theta)^2 $ is maximum which is at $ \sin^2\theta = 0,1 $ so the maximum value of the expression comes out to be $9$.

Where did I go wrong here? Or am I correct?

Comment: $u, v$ need not have the same angle as $x,y$. Further $r_1=2$ and $r_2=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way :

$$(xv-yu)^2=(x^2+y^2)(u^2+v^2)-(xu+yv)^2=36-(xu+yv)^2\le 36.$$
The equality is attained when $(x,y,u,v)=\left(\frac{4\sqrt 2}{3},-\frac 23,1,2\sqrt 2\right).$

P.S. When $(x,y,u,v)=\left(\frac{4\sqrt 2}{3},-\frac 23,1,2\sqrt 2\right)$, the followings hold :
$$xu+yv=0,\ \ \ x^2+y^2=4,\ \ \ u^2+v^2=9.$$

Comment: Quite nice but it was a multiple choice question so the answer has to be exact, not in an equality form. :)

Comment: @Shubham: Note that I proved that the maximum value of $(xv-yu)^2$ is $36$.

Comment: @Shubham This answer is exact.  We just need to check that $xu+yv=0$ is achievable.

Comment: mathlove and @slade Hmm, I see. Can you tell me which identity you used or did you open $ (xv-tu)^2 $ and then recombined the terms?

Comment: @Shubham: I've known the equation $(x^2+y^2)(u^2+v^2)-(xu+yv)^2=(xv-yu)^2$. In my opinion, this is worth remembering:)

Comment: Isnt it the [Brahmagupta Fibonacci identity?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)

Comment: @Shubham: Yes, it is. (but I have not known its name.)

Comment: @Shubham Interpreted correctly, this equation says that the norm of the product of two complex numbers is the product of the norms.  Brahmagupta used it with Pell's equation, but this too can be understood in terms of complex numbers.

Comment: I have one more question. How did you find $(x,y,u,v)$ to prove $(xu+yv) = 0$ ?

Comment: @Shubham: $xu+yv=0\iff x=-\frac{yv}{u}$, so $x^2+y^2=4\Rightarrow (-yv/u)^2+y^2=4\Rightarrow y^2(u^2+v^2)=4u^2\Rightarrow 9y^2=4u^2$ and so on. Can you take it from here?

Comment: No I tried but no :( Sorry!

Comment: @Shubham: No worry:) I needed to say one more thing. Note that all we need is to find **one example**, right? Then, after getting $9y^2=4u^2$, I set $(u,y)=(1,-2/3)$ as a simple example, then luckly this gave me the example I wrote. (Note that we don't need all possible set $(x,y,u,v)$ at all!)

Comment: So basically we used hit and trial method to find the values of $(u,y)$ right? I got that by finding just (u,y) other variables can be found but $(u,y)$ were found by hit and trial right? How do we know that these values are correct? Sorry for asking alot of questions, it must be annoying but if I don't completely understand it this will be bugging me for the rest of the night. :(

Comment: @Shubham: Of course, we can find $(x,y,u,v)$ generally, for exmaple, if we let $u\gt 0,y\lt 0$, then we have $y=-2u/3$ and $xu+yv=0\Rightarrow x=2v/3$, so $(x,y,u,v)=(2v/3,-2\sqrt{9-v^2}/3,\sqrt{9-v^2},v)$. The example I wrote is the case when $v=2\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @Shubham: To know $(x,y,u,v)=(2v/3,-2\sqrt{9-v^2}/3,\sqrt{9-v^2},v)$ is correct, check if it satisfies $xu+yv=0,x^2+y^2=4$ and $u^2+v^2=9$.

Comment: Ahh. Thank you so much! Now I have a much better understanding of this concept. Finally this is solved.:)
Hey, do you happen to know [solution to this problem](math.stackexchange.com/questions/948075/is-it-possible-to-find-the-range-of-y-frac-tan-3x-tan-x-without-grap) by any chance? :) I can't understand the last step of that problem.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2=r_1^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=r_1^2$, so $r_1=2$

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing out. Silly me! :)